# DotNetOpenAuth 4.0 and HTTPRequestInfo, NerdDinner 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dotnetopenauth, nerddinner

I'm using NerdDinner 2.0 as a base for learning DotNetOpenAuth. Great project BTW. I have it working using a DotNetOpenAuth DLL built on runtime version v2.0.50727 (came with the project). I would like to upgrade to a DotNetOpenAuth DLL built on runtime version v4.0.20926 but I get the following compile time error in the AuthController.cs file...

```
HttpRequestInfo clientResponseInfo = new HttpRequestInfo("GET", auth, auth.PathAndQuery, headers, null);
```

Exception:

> DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.HttpRequestInfo does not contain a constructor that takes 5 arguments.

Obviously I do not know what the code equivalent is in v4.0.20926.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this with:

```
HttpRequestBase clientResponesInfo = HttpRequestInfo.Create("GET", auth, headers, null);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Andrew.
I wound up doing this...hope it's correct.
HttpRequestBase clientResponseInfo = HttpRequestInfo.Create("GET", auth, headers:headers, inputStream:null);

Now, i get an error on this line...
response = RelyingParty.GetResponse(clientResponseInfo);

The error is... 
cannot convert from 'System.Web.HttpRequestBase' to 'DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.HttpRequestInfo'

Comment: @RickStickles, I'd be very interested to see the exception callstack of the "cannot convert" error you mentioned in your comment.  Can you http://pastebin.com/ it and send me a link?

Comment: Sorry Andrew but I switched over to the latest version of NerdDinner and I no longer have the issue. I was using ND 2.0 when I had the problem.